# pandoc outputs garbled on Windows console

Tags: encoding, markdown, pandoc

I encountered a problem when I'm getting started with Pandoc: I managed to repeat the example on their website and the command is:

```
pandoc
"Hello there," she said---and Sam didn't reply.
Ctrl+Z
```

The output should be:

```
<p>&quot;Hello there,&quot; She said---and Sam didn't reply.</p>
```

However, I got:

```
<p>鈥淪he said鈥?/p>
```

I guess this is caused by the encoding format, but I have no idea how to fix it.

OS: Windows10( zh-cn )

Thnaks for your help!

---

Update 17-11-29:


After changing the code page to UTF-8 with command "chcp 65001", I tried:

```
pandoc
"She said"
Ctrl + Z
```

Then I got:

```
<p>“She said”</p>
```

Notice that the two quotation marks change into CHINESE characters, which is not the outcome I want.

This issue troubles me when I convert a markdown file which contains English quotation marks into a pdf file. They just transform automatically and I have no idea how to deal with it...

Comment: I've tried on ubuntu and everything goes well. Still finding a solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `cmd`, try typing `chcp 65001` before calling pandoc. This set the encoding on cmd to UTF-8.

See:

- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3208#issuecomment-258257968 (and the next comment if you are using powershell)
- https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2101#issuecomment-94592941

Comment: Thanks for reply! This command did work but another problem appeared. I'll update my question later.

Comment: that works but not if you the call pandoc and pass a file in Windows 1252 encoding